# How to bind Ag-grid with parent child relation and show parent row data while grouping

Tags: angular

How can I bind an Ag-grid with parent child relation and show parent row data while grouping?

[image: Below is as shown]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to include a [mre] showing the data and how you are using Ag-grid.

Comment: Any one please suggest how to implement above example.